# What is W.u. as a unit in a nuclear physics context?

Tags: nuclear-physics, units, conventions, notation

In a recent paper ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.112503)/[arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01485)), of note for causing [this recent tussle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266308/do-pear-shaped-nuclei-really-have-anything-to-do-with-time-travel) over its handling by science news media, there's some strange units I can't quite puzzle out. Specifically, the abstract contains the phrase

> [...] corresponds to a reduced $B(E3)$ probability of $48(^{+25}_{-34}) \:\mathrm{W{.}u.}$

The unit is used several more times in the body of the text, but it is never explained, so I imagine it's relatively standard in nuclear physics. On the other hand, it's not in the [SI brocure](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/) so I'm surprised that PRL let a paper through that doesn't define it appropriately (however standard it may be in the field, which would make it acceptable to use unexplained in a regular Physical Review paper) in a venue that's for a general physics audience.

In any case: what is this unit, what does it mean, how does one use it, and what are the physics behind it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

W.u stands for Weisskopf unit: [[ref 1](http://web-docs.gsi.de/~wolle/BUCH/HTML/MODEL/weisskopf.pdf), [ref 2](https://books.google.rs/books?id=YgkfZgFdui8C&lpg=PA179&ots=yVJ3oYrarA&dq=Weisskopf%20unit&pg=PA179#v=onepage&q=Weisskopf%20unit&f=false)]. Despite being called a 'unit', it does not have a universal value; the value of the Weisskopf unit depends on the mass number of the nucleus in question and which transition the nucleus is undergoing ($E\lambda$ or $M\lambda$). The references contain expressions for the value of a Weisskopf unit in terms of $A$ and $\lambda$, as well as some numeric values (including $E\lambda$ for $\lambda=3$).

Answer (score 6):

In nuclear Physics estimates can be made using the [shell model of the nucleus](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuclear/shell.html) of the gamma ray transition rates in excited nucleii and such estimates are named after [Victor Weisskopf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Weisskopf).

A measured rate is compared with the Weisskopf estimate and the ratio is said to be in Weisskopf units (W.u.).