# What's a "colour triplet fermion"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-chromodynamics, beyond-the-standard-model

I'm [not a big fan](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266308/do-pear-shaped-nuclei-really-have-anything-to-do-with-time-travel/266388#266388) of Science Alert, but [this recent piece about the so-called SMASH model](http://www.sciencealert.com/this-new-hypothesis-claims-to-have-solved-5-of-the-biggest-problems-in-physics), whose gory details are apparently presented in [arXiv:1608.05414](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05414) seems reasonable. I'm curious about this "Standard Model Axion Seesaw Higgs portal inflation" model, which they summarize it as follows:

> Now, the team led by French [[sic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQnYw.png)] physicist Guillermo Ballesteros from the University of Paris-Saclay says we can add these three right-handed neutrinos to the three existing neutrinos in the standard model, plus a subatomic particle called a **colour triplet fermion**, to solve the first four problems listed above.

For the benefit of those of us with some rudimentary understanding of group theory and particle physics, but no in-depth understanding of quantum chromodynamics - what's a "colour triplet fermion"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colour triplet fermion is simply a fermion that behaves like a quark with respect to the strong force, i.e. it transforms in the triplet (or fundamental) representation of the $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ gauge group of the strong force, often denoted $\mathbf{3}$. That this is indeed the meaning here can be seen on the bottom of page 1 of the linked paper:

> [...] two Weyl fermions $Q$ and $\bar{Q}$ in the $\mathbf{3}$ and $\bar{\mathbf{3}}$ representations of $\mathrm{SU}(3)_c$ and with charges $-1/3$ and $+1/3$ under $\mathrm{U}(1)_\text{Y}$[...]

After the Higgs-like process proposed for this model happens, the two Weyl fermions will combine into a single Dirac fermion because they develop a mass, so  effectively, this "colour triplet fermion" is a very quark-like particle with the same electrical ($\pm 1/3$) and color charge as a quark and no weak force coupling *in either handedness* (this is different from quarks) as far as I can tell.

Comment: So this would break color confinement? i.e. with enough energy you could pop one of these guys into existence and have it carry a color charge as a free particle?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I don't think so, I would expect these particles to be confined just like quarks below the confinement scale. I seem to recall that adding much more (iirc, around 18) quark-like particles will eventually change the sign of the running of the coupling in QCD and give a qualitatively different theory without confinement, but this single particle won't do that.

Comment: Hmmm. So this is more of an extra non-quark quark?